# Check if only this (one) variable is set, $_GET executed also with POST type on ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a script with multiple `AJAX functions` which call the same `php_ajax.php` file.
On the `php` I check which code to execute, by checking the which `$_GET` or `$_POST vars` are setted.

I have to problems:

1) I have a `function` that pass to the `ajax` php file a variable `$_GET['lang']`. Another function pass three variables including `$_GET['lang']`. In this case both part of code on the `php ajax` file are executed. This because I check what code to execute this way:

```
//FIRST PART OF CODE
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != ''){
   //do stuff here
}

//SECOND PART OF CODE
if(isset($_POST['lang']) && isset($_POST['sub']) && isset($_POST['body'])){
   //do stuff here
}
```

I'd like to execute the first part only if ONLY `$_GET['lang']` is setted. The problem is that this part of code will be executed also if others `$var` including `$_GET['lng']` are setted. I know I could use something like `!isset($_GET['sub']` but this isn't a general solution: works only for `$sub`. Is there a general way to check if ONLY `isset($_GET['lang'])` and nothing else?

2) Why will the first part of code be executed, when I call an `AJAX` request with `POST`?
Here the script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    cache: false,
    data: {lang: lang, sub: sub, body: area_body},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result){
                alert(result);
             },
    error: function(result){
                alert('Error.');
            },
});
```

This execute both codes, even if `$_GET['lang'] shouldn't be`isset`... the`type: 'POST'`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

While posting the data add one more parameter to distinguish the operation.

```
data: {lang: lang, sub: sub, body: area_body, type: 'add'},
```

And at server side

```
if($_POST['type'] == 'add') {
     //your code
}

if($_POST['type'] == 'edit') {
     //your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is a good way. It also can help to understand what I'm doing on this part of code.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your first question, you can do like so:

```
if (count($_GET) === 1 AND !empty($_GET['lang']))
```

For your second question, try to do a `print_r($_GET);` on your PHP page.

Comment: Thank you! For the 1) the problem is that the `cache: false` of `jQuery` sends a `var` with a random code to prevent browser cache! `count($_GET) != 1`

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if `$_GET['lang']` is set, then check if it's the only `$_GET` defined by doing: `count($_GET) == 1`. In example: `if(isset($_GET['lang']) && count($_GET) == 1){ ... }`.

2) Debug your code with

`echo "<pre>" . print_r(get_defined_vars(),true) . "</pre>";`

to check if there are unwanted variables declared.

Comment: Thank you! For the 1) the problem is that the `cache: false` of `jQuery` sends a `var` with a random code to prevent browser cache! `count($_GET) != 1`

Comment: Both array are empty: `[_GET] => Array
        (
        )

    [HTTP_GET_VARS] => Array
        (
        )`